# What determines the location of a Grease P. stroke depth wise? (same layer)

Tags: grease-pencil

Now I know it is not their order in the collection. 
Also each stroke is located in the same place (X,Y,Z).
So then, what is it?

Comment: You mean the 3D position from mouse position? I guess this is similar to view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d from https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html?highlight=view3d_utils#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d

Comment: I found the reason: The time when the stroke is created determines how it will overlap with respect to the rest. However, they will still maintain the same location in space, somehow. 
Hence, if you can plan ahead your workflow, then you can arrange them accordingly. If not, then you can always push/pull them on the depth coordinate as needed. For example, if I am on the Front view, then the Y will be the coordinate for depth.